# Firefox preventDefault of alt-key

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events, keyboard-events

I am on Firefox 50.1.0 and trying to prevent the Menu-Bar drop-down (via JS) which is triggered by pressing a key (for instance <kbd>s</kbd>) while the alt key is pressed as well.

I tried preventDefault, stopPropagation and consorts but could not get it to work in any way. I could not find any working example on here or elsewhere.

Most obvious path I tried, which does not work.

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) { e.preventDefault(); };
```

Variants with onkeypress or other DOM elements do not either.

Can someone provide me with a vanilla JS example which disables/prevents the default action on <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd> or similar on Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

I think this has been disabled on newer versions of Firefox. There's been an ongoing debate about it on their [bugtracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=380637) for nearly 10 years, and it's recently been reopened.

There's no reason your function shouldn't work, and I had no success using the more specific event.altKey or a few other permutations either.

If you want to confirm I'd recommend trying it out with older versions of FF.

**Edit:** Given one of lleaff's comments, what OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works when the user has focused the page.
There is no way to prevent this behavior when the focus isn't on the webpage istelf (for instance if the user clicked on the address bar).

Comment: It definitely doesn't work on the latest version of FF - I'm on 52.x Dev Edition and neither OP's function, nor using `event.altkey` override the default behaviour. Something may have been changed, there's been a big debate over whether to allow it or not over at [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=380637) since 2007, status is reopened and it was last modified on 12/12/2016.

Comment: Weird, it works for me on FF 48.x, FDE 52.x and Nightly 53.x, all on Windows 10. Make sure you click on some part of the page's DOM before testing.

Comment: I'm in the page, with an element clicked on and no success. I'm using Linux though, so there's a chance (although I'd say it's slim) that it's related to that. All other keys are ignored as expected. Definitely weird.

Comment: I too have the issue. Firefox 50.1.0 on Windows 7. Used to work and suddenly stopped working, annoying because it is our internal system and we use alt + s to submit ticket replies (Mimic Outlook's alt+s to send)

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that some browsers will not allow you to capture certain shortcuts! A working example for the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> shortcut in Mozilla Firefox (*version: 51.0.1, Linux*):

```
window.onkeydown = function(e){
  if(e.altKey && e.keyCode == 83){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Shotcut Pressed")
  }
}
```